# Swagger/openapi add @Schema(description) to each enum value

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, springdoc

I'm creating the the API description of our application using Swagger/OpenApi V3 annotations, imported from following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I want to add the description to each enum value :

```
public enum Gender {

    @Schema(description = "NotSpecified")
    NOT_SPECIFIED,

    @Schema(description = "Male")
    MALE,

    @Schema(description = "Female")
    FEMALE;
}
```

But springdoc doesn't generate descriptions for enum.

```
Gender:
  type: string
  example: MALE
  enum:
  - NOT_SPECIFIED
  - MALE
  - FEMALE
```

Is there a way to add description to each enum value?

Answer (score 11):

I believe you can describe enum values only in desciption of enum (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/enums/). So you can do sth like this:

```java
@Schema(enumAsRef = true, description = "gender: \n" +
        "* `NOT_SPECIFIED` - NotSpecified\n" +
        "* `MALE` - Male\n" +
        "* `FEMALE` - Female\n" +
        "")
enum Gender {
    NOT_SPECIFIED,
    MALE,
    FEMALE
}
```

and the generated swagger looks quite good then.