# How can I add an enum inclusive arguments to the openapi.json?

Tags: java, enums, swagger, openapi

I have an enum with multiple arguments.

```
public enum MyEnum {
   VALUE_1("value1_string_1", "value1_string_2");

   private final String argument1;
   private final String argument2;

   MyEnum (String argument1, String argument2) {
        this.argument1 = argument1;
        this.argument2 = argument2;
   }

   public String getArgument1() {
       return argument1;
   }

   public String getArgument2() {
       return argument2;
   }
}
```

A DTO, which is part of the REST-API, uses the values of those two arguments for its fields. Field1 is set with argument1 and field2 with argument2.

```
public class MyDTO {
  private String field1;
  private String field2;
  ...
}
...
MyDTO myDto = new MyDTO();
myDto.setField1(VALUE_1.getArgument1())
myDto.setField2(VALUE_1.getArgument2())
```

How can I add the enum including the arguments to the openapi.json?
I know that I can use `@Schema(..., implementation = MyEnum.class) private String field1;`, but that would only include the enum values without arguments like:

```
"field1" : {
   "type" : "string",
   "enum" : [ "VALUE_1" ]
}
```

Also, the connection between argument 1 and argument 2 should not be lost. The user of the API should be able to see that "value1_string_1" and "value1_string_2" belong together.
The enum values (including the arguments) should be automatically added to the openapi.json to ensure it is always up to date. This means that adding a description like in this answer [Swagger/openapi add @Schema(description) to each enum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251827/swagger-openapi-add-schemadescription-to-each-enum-value) doesn't solve the problem.

I think `@Schema(... ref = "#/components/schemas/MyEnum/properties/argument1" ) private String field1;` could be part of the solution. However, the reference is useless if the enum with arguments is not in the openapi.json.

The application is using the following swagger dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The surface level problem is that in your enum code, you made argument1 and argument2 **final**. This means that they can only be assigned their value once for that instance of the enum. You then assign the initial values "value1_string_1"  and  "value1_string_2" for that enum constant (the code as posted is a bit broken, but I assume your actual enum code is in working order and copy-paste just didn't capture it correctly when posting). So if you want to assign a different value to argument1 and argument2, then you need to remove **final** from their declaration.

The second part is that enums might not be the the tool you want to use here. Enum instances have a special construction process that guarantees each decalred enum constant to only be instantiated once during the lifetime of the program. I have a feeling you really should be using a regular Class instead of an enum when working with the json framework. There are more degrees of freedom  when creating instances of the class which you likely need.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The arguments are set once through the constructor of the enum, so the final is no problem. Theoretically, I could use the enum instead of field1 and field2 in MyDTO. However, the user of the API would need to know that VALUE_1 always means that argument1 is "value1_string_1" and argument2 is "value1_string_2". So that needs to be documented somewhere. I want to add this to the openapi documentation and that is where I am currently struggling.